# MySQL Trigger not getting triggered?

Tags: mysql, triggers

So this *should* be a fairly straight forward trigger, but my MySQL isn't great, so it's undoubtably a failure on my part.
It's not updating the stats table at all, even though it should be;

```
DROP TRIGGER countryUpdate;

DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER countryUpdate AFTER INSERT ON stats
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE NewIP varchar(16);
    DECLARE NewCountry varchar(80);
    SET NewIP = inet_aton(new.vis_ip);
    SET NewCountry = (SELECT country FROM iptocountry WHERE lower_bound <= NewIP AND upper_bound >= NewIP)
    UPDATE stats
        SET Country = NewCountry

END //

DELIMITER;
```

Comment: No error, it litterally doesn't seem to get triggered.
The Country column in the stats table doesn't get updated with the country.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first off, your `UPDATE`—if it works at all—is changing *all* rows in the `stats` table, and its doing that for each row inserted. That really doesn't make much sense. At minimum, you want to add a where clause to only hit the one row you've just inserted.

Apparently, though, that can't work at all in MySQL, because ["a stored function or trigger cannot modify a table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the function or trigger."](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/stored-program-restrictions.html) (Look under “Restrictions for Stored Functions”)

So, instead, you need to use a a before insert trigger, and do a `SET new.country = NewCountry` to fix the row up before its ever inserted.

Comment: Nice catch on the lack of where clause. Imagine debugging that in production.

Comment: Oh yes, thanks for that pointer. Problem still remains that the rows aren't getting updated though...any thoughts on that?

Comment: @FizzBuzz Oh, that's because you can't update the table that's already in use, its a known limitation of MySQL—I'll update my answer. (Sorry, would have put it in before, but I remembered that and looked it up)

Comment: Ohhh, so before insert it is. Thanks, I didn't realise there was that limitation, it makes sense to have that in place though.